# Enable manual edit for the datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am using anytime date time picker plugin that can be found on this page
https://www.ama3.com/anytime/

I need the functionality that enables manual edit of the field. The author of the plugin has provided a solution for that. Unfortunately, it's not exactly what I want. Although the field is editable by default once I click on the calendar icon and set the date I cannot manually edit this field anymore. Below is the code from the plugin official page that I have tried. Is there a way to modify it somehow to make it work the way I want. Thank you.

```js
$('#ButtonCreationDemoButton').click(function(e) {
  $('#ButtonCreationDemoInput').AnyTime_noPicker().AnyTime_picker().focus();
  e.preventDefault();         
});
```

```html
<link href="https://www.ama3.com/anytime/anytime.5.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.ama3.com/anytime/anytime.5.2.0.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ButtonCreationDemoInput"/>
<button id="ButtonCreationDemoButton">
  <img src="calendar.png" alt="[calendar icon]"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unbind the keydown event to the input field and then remove the readonly attribute to make it editable.

```js
$('#ButtonCreationDemoButton').click(function(e) {
  $('#ButtonCreationDemoInput').AnyTime_noPicker().AnyTime_picker().focus();
  //remove readonly for the input field each button datepicker clicked
  $('#ButtonCreationDemoInput').attr("readonly", false);
  //unbind "keydown" event for the input field to make it editable
  $('#ButtonCreationDemoInput').unbind("keydown");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://www.ama3.com/anytime/anytime.5.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.ama3.com/anytime/anytime.5.2.0.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ButtonCreationDemoInput"/>
<button id="ButtonCreationDemoButton">
  <img src="calendar.png" alt="[calendar icon]"/>
</button>
```

Comment: Your solution has been fixed initial issue but now user can add wrong date time ex: 
2019-78-03 12:18:00.

Comment: @Casper I know. The documentation says that it's not the best practice to enable user to manually edit the value : "Warning: do not use the on-demand solution without a compelling reason, because it does not stop the user from entering a value in the wrong format! The tab-over solution (demonstrated previously) provides better validation." [link](https://www.ama3.com/anytime/)

Comment: I am also ok with that. It's an MVC application so I can add some server-side validation to prevent the wrong input. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Michael you're welcome. Don't forget to accept this answer if your issue has been fixed. To accept an answer, click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons.